# Q: Writing GraphQL resolver that uses mysql2 query

Tags: mysql, callback, graphql, apollo-server

Noob question. I'm trying to write an Apollo Server GraphQL resolver that will query and return a user from a MySQL database.

This is what I have so far:

```
const UserQueries = {
  user: (_, args, { pool }) => {
    let data = {};

    pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE `id` = ?",
      [args.id],
      (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
          data.id = rows[0].id;
          data.name = rows[0].name;
          data.username = rows[0].username;
          data.email = rows[0].email;
        }
      }
    );
    return data;
  },
};
```

`pool` is the mysql2 connection pool. If I console log inside that else statement I am getting the correct data back from the database. The problem is I can't make it go into that variable. If I move the return statement inside the else statement it still doesn't work.

Definitely a noob question but I'm totally stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work, you should check your typedef, whether the response (data object fields) matches with the respective typedef fields or not.